# Why is my promise not resolving correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```js
exports.addUser = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    username,
    email,
    password
  } = req.body;
  //hash password
  const password_hash = await hashPassword(password);
  //check whitelist
  this.checkWhitelist(email).then(function(response) {
    if (response) {
      console.log("RESOLVED TRUE")
      //POST user to Airtable
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return usersTable.create({
            email,
            username,
            password_hash,
            "email_verified": "false"
          },
          function(err) {
            if (err) {
              resolve(false);
              console.error(err);
              res.send({
                "Success": false,
                "responseCode": 502,
              })
            }
            resolve(true);
            res.send({
              "Success": true,
              "responseCode": 200,
            });
          }
        ).then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
            const EMAIL_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            jwt.sign({
                'username': username,
              },
              EMAIL_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: '1d',
              },
              (err, emailToken) => {
                const url = `http://localhost:3000/confirmation/${emailToken}`;

                transporter.sendMail({
                  to: args.email,
                  subject: 'Confirm Email',
                  html: `Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
                });
              }
            )
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
      console.log('RESOLVED FALSE')
      res.send({
        "Success": false,
        "responseCode": 403
      })
    }
  })
}
```

For some reason, the promise I created at `usersTable.create` is not resolving correctly. When I call `.then()` after, I get the error: *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.*

For context, this is the user registration flow for a webapp. First, the pass is hashed, then the email is check against a whitelist (so far this logic is working). Now I just need to verify the email, but can't get the `.then()` to call correctly.

What's going on?

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: line 36 causes the error, the .then() after the .create() promise

Comment: Suggestion: give your anonymous functions names and pull them out as top-level functions. Use variables more liberally for objects and other values so you can write `usersTable.create(data, errFunc);` or something similar in a single line. This will make your code easier to understand and reason about.

Comment: got it, thanks for the tip! I'm a very new programmer, learning as I go!

Comment: The error tells you that `usersTable.create()` returns `undefined`, not a Promise like you assume. I can't give any more information than that without some more details. What is `usersTable`? What is this `create()` method? Do you have documentation for it? Why do you think it returns a promise? Did you see something in a tutorial or some other resource online that says to write the code this way? If so, what was the resource?

Comment: You might just want to continue using `async-await` instead of a promise chain.

Comment: usersTable is a table in my Airtable DB, I wrapped the usersTable.create() in the promise syntax as I believed that would be how to create the chain into the .then(). 

The create method is from the Airtable Javascript library. I may have made a big error here using the promise, but basically I just want to prompt the .then() to execute when the .create() is successful/

Comment: I don't think you need to create a new promise inside your `this.checkWhitelist(email)`

Comment: removed the new Promise(){} wrapping around the usersTable.create() - still getting an unhandled promise error

Comment: @pai.not.pi how would you recommend implementing?

Comment: In your first `then`, you'll need to `return new promise` so it can be chained to the following `then` - but there are a few `res.send` that might mess up the flow of your response.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `then` where you `return createTable` you'll need to `return new Promise` so it can be chained to the next `then`.

If `createTable` returns a promise, you can simply write `return createTable` and get rid of the `new Promise` that wraps it.

Since you are using `async-await` earlier in the code, I'd recommend you moving to that completely as it makes the code much easier to read.

I took a stab at that,

```js
exports.addUser = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    username,
    email,
    password
  } = req.body;
  //hash password
  const password_hash = await hashPassword(password);
  //check whitelist
  try {
    const whitelist = await this.checkWhiteList(email)
    if (whitelist) {
      await usersTable.create() // shortened for readability sake.
      const EMAIL_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
      jwt.sign(
        {
          'username': username,
        },
        EMAIL_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: '1d',
        },
        (err, emailToken) => {
          const url = `http://localhost:3000/confirmation/${emailToken}`;

          transporter.sendMail({
            to: args.email,
            subject: 'Confirm Email',
            html: `Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
          });
        }
      );
    }
    res.send({
      'Success': true,
      'responseCode': 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      'Success': false,
      'responseCode': 403,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much cleaner. I implemented, and for some reason the whitelisted email is always evaluating false now - going straight to the catch(). Hmm. I console.log()'d the checkWhitelist function and doesn't look like it was even called

Comment: This might be something to do with using `this.checkWhitelist` inside an arrow function. The context of `this` is not set lexically. Where is `checkWhitelist` defined? and how is it being attached to `this`

Comment: checkWhitelist is defined in the same file, I removed the this. as I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @IgorLenterman Will probably need to see the whole file to see what the issue is, but as a general guideline using `this` inside an arrow function can get tricky. If `checkWhitelist` is in the same file then just calling it as `checkWhitelist` should suffice, the `this.` prefix is not required.